# Distribute Records By Type Id Into Repetitive Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to append repetitive columns and fill in the corresponding values from records of each type.

Source table:

| Id | TypeId | ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | valA0 | valB0 | valC0 |
| 1 | 0 | valA1 | valB1 | valC1 |
| 2 | 0 | valA2 | valB2 | valC2 |
| 3 | 1 | valA3 | valB3 | valC3 |
| 4 | 1 | valA4 | valB4 | valC4 |
| 5 | 1 | valA5 | valB5 | valC5 |
| 6 | 2 | valA6 | valB6 | valC6 |
| 7 | 2 | valA7 | valB7 | valC7 |
| 8 | 2 | valA8 | valB8 | valC8 |

Desired target output:

| ColA.0 | ColB.0 | ColC.0 | ColA.1 | ColB.1 | ColC.1 | ColA.2 | ColB.2 | ColC.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| valA0 | valB0 | valC0 | valA3 | valB3 | valC3 | valA6 | valB6 | valC6 |
| valA1 | valB1 | valC1 | valA4 | valB4 | valC4 | valA7 | valB7 | valC7 |
| valA2 | valB2 | valC2 | valA5 | valB5 | valC5 | valA8 | valB8 | valC8 |

From all that I found, this is the most matching example: [SQL - Group By Into Separate Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328127/sql-group-by-into-separate-columns).
But this solution works on two hardcoded ids, whereas in my case, the `TypeId`s are arbitrary and may be of 1 to n counts.

Is there a way other than working with cursors to achieve this result?
If cursors would be needed, I would prefer doing this in the application logic instead.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: @Larnu no, pivoting means transposing the data, but this is not my case - here batches of data should be moved to separate columns, while preserving their row layout!

Comment: No, transposing and pivoting are not the same, @Nicolas . Transposing means swapping columns to rows and rows to columns. You want to pivot the data, not transpose it, so I don't see why a dynamic pivot, which appears to be *exactly* what you want, isn't what you want. You need to elaborate further here.

Comment: @Larnu can you please explain why you think that the linked answer (and pivoting in general) would solve my issue? In the answer, values from the category column is used as column names and their values are being placed accordingly. This is not my use case, as all the data from the source table should be transferred without rotating! (to be honest, I first thought the same as you and while trying to implement, I noted that my case is different...)

Comment: YOu have 1 row for each `TypeID`, and then have pivoting on the (presumably) the row number of the `ID`. If the above doesn't answer, perhaps [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns) does. Both *pivot* your data, as that's what you're after.

Comment: @Larnu no, (1) there are multiple rows per `TypeId`, (2) the data is not being pivoted! Please have a note at the `ColX.n` and `valXn` names: all `valAn` values remain in columns `ColAn` e. g. The values have to be moved in chunks of rows to separate groups of columns. So unconventional, that I broke my mind multiple times also at the beginning of this work... :D

Comment: I gave the pivoting a go, and it looks to give exactly what you want: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PJOhw501) So can you explain why pivoting isn't what you want?

Comment: @Larnu thank you for your efforts and thank you very much for your great example! You are right, this is what I want. But (!) - as I noted in my question - I need this for arbitrary `TypeId`s. Hardcoded `TypeId`s wouldn't work therefore. Also - as to my understanding - your example is not pivoting the data! My understanding of pivot is, that data is rotated over the axes.

Comment: *"I need this for arbitrary `TypeId`s."*  Which brings us back to my original comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query); you *still* need a pivot, just a *dynamic* pivot. That you keep telling me you *don't* doesn't mean you *don't*; it seem more like you don't *want* to use a pivot and thus are saying it's isn't what you need. If you don't want a (dynamic) pivot, then do the transformation in your presentation layer (what ever that is).

Comment: @Larnu hmmm, you are probably right! I dropped this answer, as the number of rows get preserved in the given example there (for my requirement the number of rows get reduced by the batch row size of type ids - for each type id). But this may work, if adapted to my scenario. I will try this out, thank you!

Comment: If you fail, then please do update your question with your attempt, and I'll be happy to help.